# Django-tables2 Sorting TemplateColumn

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-tables2

Is it somehow possible, to add custom sort method to values generated using TemplateColumn? because on basic it tries to find column name in model and returns `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'coulmn_name' into field. Choices are: [all fields in model]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the matter of fact, this can't be done. if TemplateColumn name is based on name in model, sorting works fine. As far as I am concerned If you want present other data it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

try with the same name as the column field name in the model

model:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    field_column = models.CharField()
```

table

```
class YourTable(tables.Table):
    field_column = tables.TemplateColumn(''' your custom ''', verbose_name='your desire name')

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
```

it's work for me

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76329964/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).